# Want to run jquery fn as soon input value match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code. This will show #result div but I need to refresh page after I enter "TV" text into input field. I want to make it live so as user put text "TV" i want div should display otherwise hide it without adding it into any click hover even.

```
  HTML : 
  <input type="text" class="load" value="" name="search" placeholder="type here"> 

  Jquery:
   if ($('input.load').val() ===  'TV') {  $('#result').show();  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the benefits of instant toggle with `keyup`.  Cover all your bases using `change`.

```
var handler = function () {
  $('#result').toggle(this.value === 'TV');
};

$('input.load').bind({
  keyup: handler,
  change: handler
});
```

Comment: You were right on `keydown()`. I just removed my answer since there are so many that work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input.load').keyup(function(){
    if ($('input.load').val() ===  'TV') {  
        $('#result').show();  
    }
});
```

Comment: @JohnStrickler, you're right, but what's the best solution? Also binding to 'blur'?

Comment: Yes, I'd bind to both `keyup` and `blur`.  Alternatively, you could do `change` instead of `blur`.

Comment: you can also handle the onpaste event

Answer (score 0):

Then do this:

```
$('input.load').on("change", function() {

    if ( $( this ).val() === 'TV' )
    {
        $('#result').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$('#input.load').on('paste change keyup', function () {
    if (this.value == 'TV') {
      $('#result').show();
    }
    else {
      $('#result').hide();
    }
});
```

Handles copy + paste (using Ctrl + V), change and keyup.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$(function(){          
   $('.load').keyup(function() {
     if($(this).val() == 'tv')
         $('#result').show();         
     else
         $('#result').hide();        
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7vGs8/4/
​

Comment: Using this keyup event do you know how to do load/unload html and avoid loading duplicate html instead of show/hide div.